Flat table with macro - how to shift the notes?
I am trying to transform the table in Excel to the flat table with macro. This table contains data about passenger flows in trains and numbers of incoming and outcoming passenger in each station. Some cells contain notes. Originally it looks like this:

The final table should look so:

I tried to use the following macro:
Sub Redesigner()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim hc As Integer, hr As Integer
    Dim ns As Worksheet
     
    hr = InputBox("How many strings with names of columns?")
    hc = InputBox("How many columns on the left?")
     
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
     
    i = 1
    Set inpdata = Selection
    Set ns = Worksheets.Add
     
    For r = (hr + 1) To inpdata.Rows.Count
        For c = (hc + 1) To inpdata.Columns.Count
            For j = 1 To hc
                ns.Cells(i, j) = inpdata.Cells(r, j)
            Next j
             
            For k = 1 To hr
                ns.Cells(i, j + k - 1) = inpdata.Cells(k, c)
            Next k
             
            ns.Cells(i, j + k - 1) = inpdata.Cells(r, c)
            i = i + 1
        Next c
    Next r
End Sub

However, after the carrying out of this macro the notes were not shifted und disappeared, but they should be in the respective cells. Besides, the formatting of cells disappeared too. And instead one columns looking like "In Door 1" there should be two columns with door number and action (In or Out). What should I add in existing macro?

If you want to copy the cell with all of its custom defined properties, apply the Copy and PasteSpecial` methods something like this:
 inpdata.Cells(r, j).Copy
 ns.Cells(i, j).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

The equal sign sets only the value of the cell, because this is the defualt property.
If only the comment want to copy (without the value) apply
       ns.Cells(i, j).AddComment inpdata.Cells(r, j).Comment.Text


I tried to apply the methods Copy and PasteSpecial and replaced ns.Cells(i, j) = inpdata.Cells(r, j) with ns.Cells(i, j).Copy  inpdata.Cells(r, j).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll, ns.Cells(i, j + k - 1) = inpdata.Cells(k, c) with ns.Cells(i, j + k - 1).Copy                 inpdata.Cells(k, c).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll and ns.Cells(i, j + k - 1) = inpdata.Cells(k, c) with ns.Cells(i, j + k - 1).Copy             inpdata.Cells(r, c).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll. Unfortunately it did not work, the respective columns and cells just disappeared and nothing else happened.

In the example always Copy  is the original range to copy.  PasteSpecial  is the target.  This in your actual code is just the reverse setting. I edited  according to actual ranges. IMS.
